# data-toggle dropdown closing wrong menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dotnetnuke

I am using bootstrap navigation in DNN with the DDR module.

It is about the inner menu:

[image]

When you set your screen on a smaller resolution (below 770px) or open on mobile device, it will have an other layout:

[image]

When you click on Products for example, a menu will be shown. That menu has also submenus. But when I click on the submenu, the whole products menu gets closed... It has to show the submenu of course.

You can see it live on: http://lumenis.bondtest.nl/test-inner-menu

This is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default lumenisInnerMenu">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse lumenisListItems" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                [*>NODE]
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

[>NODE]
    <li class="[?SELECTED]dir current[/?][?NODE]HasChildren dropdownmenu [/?]">
    [?ENABLED]
        <a [?!NODE] href="[=URL]" [/?] [?TARGET]target="[=TARGET]"[/?] class="[?NODE]dropdown-toggle[/?]" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span>[=TEXT]</span>
        </a>
    [?ELSE]
        <a href="#" [?NODE] [/?]> [?NODE]
            <span>[=TEXT]</span>[/?]
        </a>
    [/?]
    [?NODE]
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown[=DEPTH]" id="[=ID]">
            [*>NODE]
        </ul>
    [/?]
    </li>
[/>]
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two menus and there are two collapsible buttons creating on small screens. So what you want then?

Comment: It is about the bootstrap menu. The one I made a screenshot of. When you click on "Products", a menu will be shown. There is an item, for example "m22" which has also a submenu. But when you click on that item, the whole menu gets closed...

Comment: In the live site there are lot of error if you check the console.. Can you clear that.. just in case those are not causing this to happen

Comment: Try to inspect in your js probably you added the event on class which is overriding because both child and parent have same class. Just a hunch.